# Customizing featureID generation in Geoserver

Tags: post, geoserver, id-generation

I would like know if it is possible to customize the featureID (fid) generation while performing WFS-T.
I looked into the option of specifying "UseExisting" value for the idgen, however, we would not want the user to specify the gml:id attribute
while posting. Rather, we would like to set this up at the geoserver level. Although not required but ideal will be to configure this customized featureID generation at the feature level.

Is there a way by which I have intercept the user request and all these extra attributes programmatically? Will it have to written as a plugin?
If so, can some one provide details on how this can be implemented?

Thanks!

Comment: One that comes to my mind is to create programmatically a transaction listener and implement the right methods to oevrride data before talking to the DBMS.

This link is a starting point: https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/GSIP-14---WFS-Transaction-handling-framework

Comment: Mind you, it might be worth bringing this question to the GeoTools or GeoServer mailing list for more in depht discussion.

Simone.